# Spaces before values in array list when there aren't supposed to be

Tags: php, arraylist, shuffle

I am having spaces before values in my randomize I made for a name, using prefix root and suffix. Here is a link to what I mean [example on my website](http://citadelwars.net/RPG.php) and if you look at the bottom of the plot it says the name, but with spaces in between, only sometimes. Which to me, makes no sense at all. I have been struggling with this for a while and I can't figure out how to fix this. I will provide links for my source of the PHP as well being inside text files. [source for example](http://citadelwars.net/RPG.txt) Please help me as this problem may seem minor, but it continues to baffle me as it does not make sense.

Comment: Where a re the spaces exactly? Please don't make me read every single char :)

Comment: Lol, I see what you did there, it's at the end of the echo where it puts together the prefix root and suffix of the name.

Comment: See my answer below. BTW you have a new registered user!

Comment: Hey sebastien, are you going rogue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explode your text files with by `"\n"` but your text files use `"\r\n"` (CRLF: carriage return + line feed). so you must explode like this:

```
$first_prefix = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents('RPG/name/1prefix.txt'));
$first_root = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents('RPG/name/1root.txt'));
$first_suffix = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents('RPG/name/1suffix.txt'));
```

You could go about it many different ways but if all your text files are created the same way that should solve your problem.

Another way would be to preventively trim each piece of the string (even if you exploded correctly, just in case some whitespace snuk in the text file):

```
echo "<div align='center'>" . $settings[0] . "<br /> " .
$objectives[0] . "<br /> " . $antagonists[0] . "<br /> " .
$complications[0] . "<br />" .
trim( $first_prefix[0] ) . trim( $first_root[0] ) . trim( $first_suffix[0] );
```